# How to get represent undefined value C++?

Tags: c++, undefined

I have code that calculates two slopes and compares them, and if they are the same I get their values.

However if one slope is undefined the program crashes. I need to know if they are the same even if they are undefined. I can't use any other negative or positive integers as that would mess up my code big time.

I would prefer a word value, like 5/0 = undefined, but not sure how I could do that.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int r = 5/0;

int main()
{
    // Instead of crashing, this should tell me this value is undefined somehow.
    cout << r << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

How can I handle the case were the slope is exactly vertical?

Comment: Re: "Please don't ask me to post my code it's too long and no one read it last time." Actually I will ask you to post your code, otherwise nobody can make any reasonable attempt at answering your question. Nobody read it last time precisely because it's too long. Make a [short, self contained, correct, compilable example](http://www.sscce.org/) and we can do a better job at giving you a better answer that actually solves your problem.

Comment: its a simple concept, dont need a code

Comment: Yes, you do. Are you using `float`s, `double`s, `int`s, etc.? What does the structure of your code? How are you handling exceptions, if you're handling exceptions at all? The devil is in the details.

Comment: #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int r=5/0;

int main()
{
    cout << r << endl;
    return 0;
}

Comment: If by undefined you mean `a/0`, then you could catch the signal sent by the OS, or just compare the denominator with 0.

Comment: There ISN'T a way to represent that somethig is undefined if you CAN'T use any of the values within "int" to represent it. You need some way to describe, beyond the value stores in r to say "this value isn't valid" (and of course, you won't receive that from 5/0 - you need to have 5 and 0 in two variables and figure out that the dividend is zero, so can't be divided). Of course, the ANSWER given here is definitely a useful suggestion - "don't do that".

Answer (score 0):

You should represent slopes in a way that is always defined (such as angles). If there's another step in your program where the result is not defined for mathematical reasons, you could raise an exception.

Also for getting the angle from a vector x,y, you should use atan2 http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/atan2

```
 double theta = atan2(y,x) ; // this is always fine
```

To compare two angles, defined by vectors x1,y1 and x2,y2:

```
double th1 = atan2(y1,x1) 
double th2 = atan2(y1,x1) 

const double mypi=3.141592653589793238463;

double angleDiff = pi - abs(abs(th1 - th2) - pi); 

if(angleDiff*10<=mypi){
    cout << " angles are within 0.1 pi (that is 18 degr) <<endl; 
}
```

Also remember that when comparing floating point values, you should not expect *exact* matches, except for a few special cases.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is very old but as I am trying to solve an almost identical issue I have decided to post an answer.

I would suggest one way is using a null pointer to identify an undefined value. In my case using angles is wildly inaccurate as I am using the gmp (gnu multi precision library) and I need perfect precision for huge bit sizes starting at 64bits and climbing.

floating point simply does not cut it.

As I see it you have two choices a flag to be tested separately from retrieving the slope or tested after retrieving the slope.
I cannot see an alternative that doesn't involve throwing an exception

```
class line {
    bool vertical;
    bignum slope;

    // one method two functions
    bool is_vertical(){return vertical;}
    bignum slope() {return slope}

    //alternative method 
    bignum *slope() {if (vertical) return NULL; else return &slope}
}
```

Most code needs to handle a vertical line differently to any other line any way so its not an onerous task to deal with the vertical line in an if statement

```
if ((slope = line.slope())==NULL){//vertical
    // do some vertical stuff 
    cout << "line is vertical";
} else {
    // do some other line stuff with bignum *slope
    cout "slope is " << *slope;
}
```